# How can I select the id of the outermost element inside a parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, element, getelementbyid, selectors-api

For example is I have a `<div>`, so inside my `<div>` i have some elements with id such as `<label>`, `<span>` and `<p>` the first element that occurs on my code is the `<p>`

```
<div id = 'cont' class = 'inc'>
   <p id = '1' class = 'box'>
      <label id ='aa' class = 'innerbox'><span id = 'aaa' class = 'innerboxs'></span></label>
   </p>

 <p id = '2' class = 'box'>
          <label id ='aa' class = 'innerbox'><span id = 'aaa' class = 'innerboxs'></span></label>
       </p>

 <p id = '3' class = 'box'>
          <label id ='aa' class = 'innerbox'><span id = 'aaa' class = 'innerboxs'></span></label>
       </p>
</div>
```

Base on the example above, after the `<div>`, `<p>` is it's very first child element that occurs. Let's assume that I want to get their ID through this code.

```
function checkContents(){
    var output = "";
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.inc [id]'),
    ids = Array.prototype.map.call(elements, function(element) {
        return element.id;
    });
    output = 'ids = ' + JSON.stringify(ids, null, '  ');
    alert(output);
}
```

This function outputs all the id inside the `<div>` with the `inc` class. I just want to get the id of the `<p>` with the classname of box, how can I get it?

Comment: Don't used to same ID for multiple case in a single page. Used only one ID for in a page if you are using multiple  than used to Class not ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure, there will only be `<p>` elements inside the `div.inc`

then you can simply do

`var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.inc p');`

If you're not sure what are the first level elements, then you can simply use the selector to select only the immediate children like

`var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.inc > *'),`

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.inc [id]'),
```

with:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.inc>*'),
```

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0POfOoJk2Y82eYEEEege?p=preview) for it

Answer (score 1):

Replace following line

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.inc [id]')
```

with

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.inc p[id]'),
```